# Cloudwatch insights query to group by field

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

Trying to write a cloud watch insights query to concatenate error messages for the same timestamp to be displayed as one row rather than multiple rows in the result.

So far I have tried the below query.

```
fields @timestamp,concat(@message)
| filter @message like /(?i)(Exception|error|fail|)/
| limit 20
```

This displays the results are below.

```
2019-09-12T12:17:09.803+10:00 12:17:09,720 |-ERROR in A
2019-09-12T12:17:09.803+10:00 12:17:09,720 |-ERROR in B
2019-09-12T12:17:09.803+10:00 12:17:09,720 |-ERROR in C
```

I am expecting the below result.

2019-09-12T12:17:09.803+10:00 12:17:09,720 |- ERROR in A -ERROR in B -ERROR in C

Comment: `code` correction filter @message like /(?i)(Exception|ERROR|fail)/

Answer (score 8):

The `concat` operator is not an aggregating function, so will not do what you are looking for.

Rather, it is used for concatinating multiple values in a single row, e.g.

```
fields @timestamp, concat("Got message ", @message, " from stream ", @logStream)
```

would give you

```
| 2019-09-12T12:17:09.803+10:00 12:17:09,720 | Got message bla from stream some_log_stream |
```

As far as I know there is no way to aggregate strings from multiple rows into a single row.